# How can I make the computer see a SATA DVD drive as a USB DVD drive?

Tags: windows-7, vmware, optical-drive

So, I am using VMware View for thin PCs and a user wants to use the local DVD drive in the VM. It seems that the only way to pass any device in is by USB. I was wondering if there is a way to pass the SATA DVD drive from the host machine in to the VM as a USB drive?

The VM is on the server, not on the local machine.

This is a VM on a thin PC in a library. The user needs to routinely play DVDs as part of the person's job.

Comment: The two controllers are completely different. SATA is one technology and had its own controllers and drivers. USB, the same, has different controllers and drivers. You will need a SATA to USB bridge to convert the interfaces.

Comment: Yea, I realize that. I was wondering if there is any way to just trick the computer into thinking that is what the DVD drive is. Like a virtual DVD drive as a USB device or something on the host machime

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure this can't be done.

Comment: You cannot pass  SATA drives the same way you can pass USB drives.  The VM has a virtual optical disk drive, tell the vm software to attach the disk in the actual drive, instead of an .iso file.

Comment: I know that I cannot pass SATA drives like USB drives. That is the purpose of my question. The VM is on the server, not on the local machine so I can't attach the disk in the drive.

Comment: Have you tried ripping this disc to an ISO and then mounting that?

Comment: It is not just one disk. I updated the question to try to be more clear.